# How can I limit my searches to a particular date range?

Tags: support

I'm working on integrating a framework that was updated in February with another system. My request is fairly routine so I'm sure its been posted before but I'm receiving too many results in search to easily find an answer. Given the system update was quite dramatic I'm confident the answers I'm seeking for would have mostly come up not long after the February change.

With this in mind how can I format my search request so it only shows results from February to April?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`created:2015-02..2015-03-31`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=created%3A2015-02..2015-03-31) should do the trick. For details, see: [Advanced Search Options](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching)

Comment: Excellent, thank-you. I didn't realize this wiki page existed. There' s nothing about dates on the quick view menu about advanced search options.